# CS-Script persistent cache for better performance when loading scripts

Tags: c#, caching, scripting, persistence

Is there a way to persist CS-Script internal assembly cache between subsequent application's runs?

Used component: http://www.csscript.net/

The desired behavior is: 
when I compile an assembly form a script string and I close the application, the next time I run the application the compiled assembly with matching script string is found and no recompilation is needed.

This question is follow-up of another question:
[Is there a way to call C# script files with better performance results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061530/is-there-a-way-to-call-c-sharp-script-files-with-better-performance-results/12199361#12199361)

Here is my code, but every script string requires recompilation with every restart of parent .NET application.

```
public interface ICalculateScript
{
    Exception Calculate(QSift qsift, QSExamParams exam);
}

...
void Calculate(string script)
{
    CSScript.CacheEnabled = true; 
    //Can following command use built-in cache to load assembly, compiled by this line of code, but by another instance of this app which run in the past and has been meanwhile closed? 
    Assembly assembly = = CSScript.LoadCode(script, null);

    AsmHelper asmHelper = new AsmHelper(assembly);
    ICalculateScript calcScript = (ICalculateScript)asmHelper.CreateObject("Script");
    calcScript.Calculate(this, exam);
}
```

Related problem:
The folder of temp scripts created by Cache in CS Script C:\Users\vdohnal\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache\2015108000 has 41 MB and growing with files few months old.

In the output window of WPF App there are first chance exceptions:
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'ESClient.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\vdohnal\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache\2015108000\af621e10-d711-40d7-9b77-0a8e7de28831.tmp.compiled'
C:\Users\vdohnal\AppData\Local\Temp\CSSCRIPT\Cache\2015108000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer fom Oleg Shilo which pointed me in the right direction:

> The cache folder indeed grows as new scripts are compiled/loaded. This
>   is the nature of the caching. It seems that it "grows without control"
>   though it is not. Once cache is created for a given script file it is
>   never duplicated and the new cache update is always written over the
>   existing one.
>
> The problem in your case is that every time you load the file you give
>   it a unique name thus you are creating a new unique cache. To fix it
>   you need to start using the same name for the script file every time
>   you load/execute it.
>
> Alternatively you can completely take over the caching location and
>   specify what ever cache name you want. It is that second parameter
>   that you pass null for:
>
> ```
>  Assembly assembly = CSScript.LoadCode(script, null);
> ```

I used following code:

```
if (assemblyFileName == null)
    assembly = CSScript.LoadCode(script, null); //In case there is no name specified - when my custom temp folder cannot be created etc.
else
    assembly = CSScript.LoadCode(script, assemblyFileName, false, null);  //Specify full path and file name with extension
```

Thanks to this I have complete control over cached assembly name and location.
If cached assembly with appropriate script already exists, I can simply load it instead of compiling a new one:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
AsmHelper asmHelper = new AsmHelper(assembly)
```

The speed of initial loading is better and there is no uncontrollably growing cache.